# how can i split a string

Tags: java

Hi I want to split a string as only two parts. i.e. I want to split this string only once.

```
EX: String-----> hai,Bye,Go,Run
```

I want to split the above string with comma(,) as two parts only

i.e

```
String1 ---> hai 

String2 ---->Bye,Go,Run
```

Please help me how can I do it.

Answer (score 9):

Use [String.split(String regex, int limit)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) method:

```
String[] result = string.split(",", 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] result = string.split("\\s*,\\s*" ,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic Java knowledge...
Have a look at String class definition before asking here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

You should follow some Java tutorial before starting programming in Java.

Answer (score 0):

if you check out the Java Doc of string

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

You'll find one of the methods is

```
split(String regex)
```

then what you want is to use a regex like "," to get a table of strings

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "hai,Bye,Go,Run";
String str1 = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(','));
String str2 = str.substring(str.indexOf(',')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String method:

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

e.g. (not tested)

```
String str = "hai,Bye,Go,Run"
str.split(",", 2);
```

Comment: Better assign the `String[]` that `split` returns to something, otherwise a Java beginner might think `str` just became an array...

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="hai,Bye,Go,Run";
```

//String 1

```
String str1=str.substring(0,str.indexOf(','));
```

//String 1

```
String str1=str.substring(str.indexOf(',')+1,str.length);
```

done :)